# Prevent boost::asio::io_context stopping on empty poll call

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

This code calls the posted handle

```cpp
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    boost::asio::post(ioc, []{ std::cout << "lol" << std::endl; });
    ioc.poll();
```

whereas this doesn't:

```cpp
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    ioc.poll(); // empty, set internal state to stopped_
    boost::asio::post(ioc, []{ std::cout << "lol" << std::endl; });
    ioc.poll(); // doesn't work as stopped() now returns true
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yZSyHEQPVj2FG2sS)

Is it by design? If is, why? Can I configure `io_context` somehow to change this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

io_service/io_context are designed to stop when they run out of work¹.

The docs for [`io_service`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.stopping_the_io_context_from_running_out_of_work) and [`io_context`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context.stopping_the_io_context_from_running_out_of_work) contain:

> #### Stopping the io_context from running out of work
>
> Some applications may need to prevent an io_context object's run() call from returning when there is no more work to do. For example, the io_context may be being run in a background thread that is launched prior to the application's asynchronous operations. The run() call may be kept running by creating an object of type boost::asio::executor_work_guard<io_context::executor_type>:
>
> ```
> boost::asio::io_context io_context;
> boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>
>   = boost::asio::make_work_guard(io_context);
> ...
> ```
>
> To effect a shutdown, the application will then need to call the io_context object's stop() member function. This will cause the io_context run() call to return as soon as possible, abandoning unfinished operations and without permitting ready handlers to be dispatched.
>
> Alternatively, if the application requires that all operations and handlers be allowed to finish normally, the work object may be explicitly reset.
>
> ```
> boost::asio::io_context io_context;
> boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>
>   = boost::asio::make_work_guard(io_context);
> ...
> work.reset(); // Allow run() to exit.
> ```

Note that the "old-fashioned" Asio interface used a less generalized `io_service::work` object:

```
io_service ios;
io_service::work work(ios); // old interface!
```

This would then require you to do extra work for to be able to reset it:

```
asio::io_service ios;
std::optional<asio::io_service::work> work(ios);
// ...
work.reset();
```

### Restarting

Finally when the context *did* run out of work, you will have to `restart()` it before re-using it:

[image]

### Rationale

I think the rationale for the design comes from the library not having any
opinions about how the service is run in terms of scheduling and threading, in
combination with the guarantee that `io_context`/`io_service` must be
thread-safe². See [docs for
background](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html).

---

¹ Sidenote: Likewise, `thread_pool` (which is-a `execution_context` just like `io_context` is) is not designed for re-use (see e.g. [Boost asio thread_pool join does not wait for tasks to be finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61328430/boost-asio-thread-pool-join-does-not-wait-for-tasks-to-be-finished/62399256#62399256))

² Except object lifetime (construction/destruction), of course

Comment: By the way, in the new executor model it *is* possible to implement executors that do not refcount on work by implementing [`on_work_started` / `on_work_finished` operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Executor1.html) as no-op. But this is getting into extension/implementation territory a bit.

Answer (score 2):

This documented (not in best place, it should be mentioned in `poll` documentation):

[io_context::restart - develop](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/restart.html)

> [io_context::restart](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/restart.html)
>
> Restart the [`io_context`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html) in preparation for a subsequent `run()` invocation.
>
> void restart();
>
> This function must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` functions when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the [`io_context`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html) being stopped or running out of work. After a call to `restart()`, the [`io_context`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html) object's `stopped()` function will return `false`.
>
> This function must not be called while there are any unfinished calls to the `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` functions.

So basically you need to add `restart` to make it work.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/aXzz5GCAIMIvStnl

Here is [an extra clue](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4B1tsVPFpn0FjsYf) why.

Comment: Worth to add: the `restart` function does NOT remove awaiting ready handlers. Still, I don't have idea why the interface is designed like that. This is not what I would expect.

Comment: Just use a work guard (`asio::io_service ::work`, or the more modern `make_executor_work_guard` helper)

Comment: @sehe this is exactly what I was looking for. Never seen this in documentation. Will you post an answer?

Comment: @jaskmar [done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63394687/85371) (I misremembered the name of `make_work_guard` as well - the class is `exucutor_work_guard<>` indeed)