# Boost-Asio io_context post after run

Tags: c++, boost, reactor

I am new to `Boost::asio` and I am currently looking at `io_context`.
In the docs https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html shown is the following example:

```
{
  ...
}

...

boost::asio::io_context io_context;

// Submit a function to the io_context.
boost::asio::post(io_context, my_task);

// Submit a lambda object to the io_context.
boost::asio::post(io_context,
    []()
    {
      ...
    });

// Run the io_context until it runs out of work.
io_context.run();
```

However, I would like to be able to `post` even after `io_context.run()` has been called.
Essentially, something like this:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int value = -1;

void my_task()
{
  value = 42;
}

int main() {
  boost::asio::io_context io_context;

  // Submit a function to the io_context.
  //boost::asio::post(io_context, my_task);

  // Run the io_context until it runs out of work.
  io_context.run();

  boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> work(io_context.get_executor());

  // Submit a lambda object to the io_context.
  boost::asio::post(io_context,
      []()
      {
        my_task();
      });

  assert(value == 42);

}
```

After compiling the above with `g++ -o a example.cpp -lboost_system -lpthread` I am getting an assertion failure. What is the "right" way to accomplish this?

Comment: Looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63378534/1387438

Comment: you need to call `run` from a separate thread

Answer (score 2):

Either run the io_context on a separate thread, or, indeed use the execution context that already has that built in.

### Using a manual thread

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00c859fb5cacf93f)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int value = -1;

void my_task() { value = 42; }

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    auto work = make_work_guard(io_context);

    std::thread thread([&] { io_context.run(); });

    // submit to the io_context
    post(io_context, my_task);

    work.reset();
    thread.join();

    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
42
```

### Using `asio::thread_pool`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81c567e44db33e11)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int value = -1;

void my_task() { value = 42; }

int main() {
    boost::asio::thread_pool io(1);

    post(io, my_task);

    io.join();

    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

As you can see it's basically the same, but

- less code
- less `work` (literally)
- more correct (see e.g. [Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught))
- trivial to make multi-threaded `thread_pool io(16);` or just using the default `thread_pool io;`

Answer (score 0):

`io_context::run()` blocks as long as there is work to do. In your first example, you could just wait until both the `post`ed tasks are finished. After that, `io_context::run()` returns and you can submit new work and call `run()` again. If you don't want this *sequential* behavior but rather submit tasks while the `io_context` works on tasks, you need a second thread, that executes `io_conext::run()`. You can create one for example like this:

```
#include <thread>

//...

std::thread my_thread( [&](){ io_context.run(); } );

// post more work here

// wait for it to finish
my_thread.join();
```

Make sure that the `io_context` object lives longer than the thread, if you use the lamda capture by reference like in this example.