# Queueing work into a Boost Thread_Pool within a loop

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool, boost-asio

I am trying to use a boost thread_pool to keep running the same functions in a while loop, but am running into some issues. Here is a snippet of my code. When I run it my program just starts eating memory until my computer doesn't have any left. From debugging, I think this is because the queue is just growing so fast, and the functions can't be processed fast enough. I tried putting a pool.wait() and pool.join() inside the loop, and that works for the first iteration, but every iteration after that, it does not wait and the work is not being processed.

Previously I used a parallel for loop to call my functions and this worked fine. But as I added more functions that need to be processed, I started to need the ability to limit how many functions are being processed at a time, but I still want to queue everything up so it all gets done. Which is why I have 6 functions, but a pool size of 4.

Edit: I want to essentially queue up the 6 functions in batches and wait for all 6 to finish before adding the next set of 6 to the queue. The issue with pool.wait() and pool.join() is that they set an internal flag that prevents the threads from getting anymore work. And I couldn't find a way to reset this flag.

```
driver()
{
   auto foo1 = [&](){...};
   auto foo2 = [&](){...};
   auto foo3 = [&](){...};
   auto foo4 = [&](){...};
   auto foo5 = [&](){...};
   auto foo6 = [&](){...};

   boost::asio::thread_pool pool(4);
   while(isRunning)
   {
       boost::asio::post(pool, [&foo1] {foo1(); });
       boost::asio::post(pool, [&foo2] {foo1(); });
       boost::asio::post(pool, [&foo3] {foo1(); });
       boost::asio::post(pool, [&foo4] {foo1(); });
       boost::asio::post(pool, [&foo5] {foo1(); });
       boost::asio::post(pool, [&foo6] {foo1(); });
       //boost::asio::post(pool, foo1);
       //boost::asio::post(pool, foo2);
       //boost::asio::post(pool, foo3);
       //boost::asio::post(pool, foo4);
       //boost::asio::post(pool, foo5);
       //boost::asio::post(pool, foo6);
       //pool.join();
       //pool.wait();
   }
   pool.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to recreate the pool inside the loop. That might create considerable thread creation/shutdown overhead though.

So, short of that, you might want a fork-join executor. See [the example](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/example/cpp14/executors/fork_join.cpp) or this answer: [Boost asio thread_pool join does not wait for tasks to be finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61328430/boost-asio-thread-pool-join-does-not-wait-for-tasks-to-be-finished/62399256#62399256)

[Also, explore the question there for a similar situation to yours.]

Finally, if you both

- *"I started to need the ability to limit how many functions are being processed at a time"*

but also

- *"still want to queue everything up so it all gets done"*

you might need to consider persisting the queue to a database/shared memory so you don't run into memory limitations

Comment: your first solution worked as a good temporary fix while I look into that thread you posted. Thank you! And sorry I should have been a little more clear on my needs at the end. I want to limit how many of the 6 functions are being processed at once, but I want to queue them up in batches and wait for all 6 to complete before I queue up the next set of 6. I don't want it to just queue infinitely since that cause memory issues, but the wait() function stops the threads from getting more work.

Comment: Ah. So the fork-join executor is definitely what you want, but you **can** hack it using a deadline_time that "never" expires, unless you manually cancel it. You could then coordinate using an atomic counter to see when it reaches that point.  This is like emulating a `barrier` using async primitives.