# Wait until A job (as starkly opposed to ALL jobs) posted to boost::asio::thread_pool completes?

Tags: c++, threadpool, boost-asio

I post multiple jobs to a `boost::asio::thread_pool`, and I want to process their results as soon as each individual result is available. I would 1000× prefer an "event loop" idiom for this over callback idiom, because the event loop idiom automatically does synchronization for me: only one thread consumes the results and writes them to an aggregate data structure without needing to synchronize access to it. The documentation is unclear on how to do this; the examples given use lots of difficult concepts and seem about 10× more complicated than a typical instance of the event loop idiom should be.

Is the event loop idiom supported by `boost::asio` at all?

Answer (score 0):

Asio has the proactor model. Basically, a service is "run" by executing new handlers when they are ready. If you view a handler as an event, then you will see that you already have what you are after.

The pool operates on an event loop per thread. So, you have a task, and have it post the continuation event to the pool. Same guarantees that you describe.

### Demo

The following code runs `taskB` that depends on `taskA` as soon as `taskA` completes. It runs four of these tasks in parallel:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0b745bacb754fad)**

```
// #define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std::literals;
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

static auto const start = now();
static void randelay()
{
    thread_local auto gen = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<>(100, 800),
                                      std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(gen() * 1ms);
}

int main()
{
    auto taskB = [](int resultFromTaskA) {
        randelay();
        static std::mutex mx;
        std::lock_guard lk(mx);
        std::cout << "at " << std::setw(4) << (now() - start) / 1ms
                  << "ms taskB resultFromTaskA: " << resultFromTaskA
                  << std::endl;
    };

    boost::asio::thread_pool ctx;
    auto executor = ctx.get_executor();
    auto taskA    = [=](int payload) {
        randelay();
        post(executor, std::bind(taskB, payload*payload));
    };

    for (auto i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
        post(ctx, std::bind(taskA, i));

    ctx.join();
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
at  234ms taskB resultFromTaskA: 16
at  837ms taskB resultFromTaskA: 4
at 1214ms taskB resultFromTaskA: 1
at 1290ms taskB resultFromTaskA: 9
```

And with enabled handler tracking:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have seen code like this in the examples, and the reason I am looking for something better is because this is complicated and ugly. The ugliest part is the producer being required to know the consumer, but the need for explicit synchronization is nasty too.

Comment: There is no need for explicit synchronization. The only sync I added was to protect std::cout. How would an event based solution make things better? Can't you pass the continuation ("consumer") to the producer? If you make that follow async initiation protocol you will even be able to use it with futures, inside coroutines, with co_await etc.

Comment: If you argue that events make things better for the decoupling, what's stopping you from pushing events into a (lock-free?) queue and consume that? My bet is that you reach catch-22 because you'll have to synchronize on the queue in one way or another. This is the nature of events.

Comment: Oh another thing, you didn't ask about barrier-like semantics, but perhaps look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61328430/boost-asio-thread-pool-join-does-not-wait-for-tasks-to-be-finished/62399256#62399256