# boost::get_pointer error during boost::asio::post on thread pool

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to understand thread pools using boost.
I've written the following code:

```
#include <boost/asio/post.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/thread_pool.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class A {
public:
    void asyncFunc(int i)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        std::cout<< i ;
    }

    void beforeFunc()
    {
        std::cout<< "Before\n";
    }

    void afterFunc()
    {
        std::cout<< "After\n";
    }

    void otherFunc()
    {
        boost::asio::thread_pool pool(4);
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            beforeFunc();
            boost::asio::post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, 3));
            boost::asio::post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, 0));
            boost::asio::post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, 2));
            boost::asio::post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, 1));
            afterFunc();
        }
        pool.join();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.otherFunc();
}
```

But I get errors related to boost::get_pointer. (https://wandbox.org/#)
The idea would be to execute 4 asyncFuncs in parallel, but always after beforeFunc() and before afterFunc() as they will be dependent.
Do you know what I'm doing wrong in this code, or how could I achieve better what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding non-static member functions. The first argument for non-static member function is the implicit `this` argument. You are passing integers there. Add the missing `this`:

```
        post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, this, 3));
        post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, this, 0));
        post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, this, 2));
        post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, this, 1));
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1663e56c2fd20772)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A {
  public:
    void asyncFunc(int i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        std::cout << i;
    }

    void beforeFunc() { std::cout << "Before\n"; }

    void afterFunc() { std::cout << "After\n"; }

    void otherFunc() {
        boost::asio::thread_pool pool(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10/*00*/; i++) {
            beforeFunc();
            post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, this, 3));
            post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, this, 0));
            post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, this, 2));
            post(pool, boost::bind(&A::asyncFunc, this, 1));
            afterFunc();
        }
        pool.join();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    A a;
    a.otherFunc();
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Before
After
Before
After
Before
After
Before
After
Before
After
Before
After
Before
After
Before
After
Before
After
Before
After
1032321030213012302130123012032131023102
```

### Achieving What You're Trying

You won't really be done because you don't synchronize before the `afterFunc()`. You can do that in various ways:

- [C++ thread pool using boost::asio::thread_pool, why can't I reuse my threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006664/c-thread-pool-using-boostasiothread-pool-why-cant-i-reuse-my-threads/70006785#70006785)
- [Wait until A job (as starkly opposed to ALL jobs) posted to boost::asio::thread_pool completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551240/wait-until-a-job-as-starkly-opposed-to-all-jobs-posted-to-boostasiothread/67551578#67551578)