# How to deal: if boost::asio::post is endlessly repeated, when boost::asio::thread_pool destructor is triggered?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, threadpool

I have a class wrapper for `boost::asio::thread_pool m_pool`. And in wrapper's destructor i join all the threads:

```
ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    m_pool.join();
    cout << "All threads in Thread pool were completed";
}
```

Also I have queue method to add new task to threadpool:

```
void ThreadPool::queue(std::function<void()> task, std::string label)
{
    boost::asio::post(m_pool, task);
    cout << "In Thread pool was enqueued task: " << label;
}
```

In boost [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/thread_pool/_thread_pool.html) for thread_pool destructor is said:

> Automatically stops and joins the pool, if not explicitly done beforehand.

How to deal with the situation when I have boost::asio::post endlessly repeated, when boost::asio::thread_pool destructor is triggered?
Will I got something like an endless thread_pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1+1 == 2: just remove the `join()`. As you've noted, that risks blocking indefinitely. You don't want/need that, so why ask for it?

Alternatively, you could manually stop and join the pool. I'd suggest removing the destructor.

Comment: Yeah, i guess manual `atomic_bool m_stop` variable will be pretty nice solution for me. It will give me the flexibility to choose whether i want to stop or to join all threads.

Comment: Also consider a timeout on any graceful shutdown. `stop()` if graceful shutdown blocks for longer than the acceptable time limit.

Comment: Ok. Thank you!
Hmm... I guess, the solution of not `boost::asio::post`-ing new tasks from the moment of `stop==true` is much more better than using `stop()`.

Comment: It depends on what posts what :) Some operations are still required for graceful shutdown. The important thing is that `stop()` is rarely the correct way to shutdown, just good to also keep in mind sometimes a connection will get stuck and you don't want it to prevent a server from restarting, e.g.